How to handle file upload in Node.js with microservices and Docker: Mount the folder to the container or not?
I am working on a microservices project using Node.js and Docker. Each microservice runs as a separate container (e.g., api-gateway, auth-service, etc.).
Currently, the API Gateway is responsible for handling file uploads and storing them in the server's file system. The project structure looks like this:
-- myproject/api-gateway
-- myproject/auth-service
myproject/upload/  (This is where the uploaded files are stored).
The upload folder is not mounted to the upload-service container, so files are stored directly on the host file system.
Questions:

Is this approach suitable for a microservices architecture?
What improvements or best practices can I apply to make this system more scalable, secure, and efficient?

My goals are:

Avoid storing files inside the API Gateway container.
Ensure the architecture is scalable and can handle high traffic.
Keep the system manageable and future-proof.


I don't think microservices or monolith matters here. But you're limiting yourself to run on one machine which imposes some limits on scalability.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
